# move specific lines to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.array(['2021-04-11', '2021-04-12', '2021-04-13', '2021-04-14',
                                     '2021-04-15', '2021-04-16', '2021-04-17', '2021-04-18',
                                     '2021-04-19', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-21', '2021-04-22',
                                     '2021-04-23', '2021-04-24', '2021-04-25', '2021-04-26',
                                     '2021-04-27', '2021-04-28', '2021-04-29', '2021-04-30', 
                                     '2021-05-01' ,'2021-05-02', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-04',
                                     '2021-05-05', '2021-05-06', '2021-05-07']),
                    'value': np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
                                      24,25,26,27])})
```

I want to split it to 3 parts (train,val and test).

For example:

```
split=0.7 # split perc
last=7 # keep 7 last days for test data

split_idx = int(df.shape[0] * split)
train_df = df[:split_idx]
val_df = df[split_idx:-last]
test_df = df[(train_df.shape[0] + val_df.shape[0]):]
```

So, now I have:

```
len(train_df), len(val_df), len(test_df) = 18, 2, 7
```

I want the lengths to be divisible by 7, so:

```
if len(train_df) % 7 != 0:
    # move those rows to the beginning of val_df
    val_df.loc[0] = 
    # drop those rows from train_df
    train_df.drop(train_df.tail(len(train_df) % 7).index, inplace=True)
```

If the len of train_df is not divisible by 7, then I want to move those last rows of data to the beginning of val_df data and then drop those from train_df. The same applies to val_df. The test_df will always have at lest 7 values, so if it greater I will just drop them.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , I found an answer!

```
if len(train_df) % 7 != 0:
    # move those rows to the beginning of val_df
    rows = train_df.tail(len(train_df) % 7)
    val_df = pd.concat([val_df.iloc[:len(val_df)], rows, val_df.iloc[len(val_df):]]).sort_index()
    # drop those rows from train_df
    train_df.drop(train_df.tail(len(train_df) % 7).index[0:], inplace=True)
```